# Cannot get a dialog box to open from inside a jqgrid edit form unless the html directly entered into the dialog function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jqgrid

I have tried various ways of describing "dialog-1" to no avail.  The same code works fine as part of the page body if the dialog function is called from there.  The same code does not work from inside the form.

Thanks for your help.

This function displays the dialog box just fine.

```
function helpSThtml () {
$(function() {
    $( "<div id='dialog-1' title='Dialog Title goes here...'>This my first jQuery UI Dialog!</div>" ).dialog({
        height: 140,
        modal: true,
        open: function (event, ui) {
            $('.ui-dialog').css('z-index',950);
            $('.ui-widget-overlay').css('z-index',949);
        },
    });
});
}
```

This function appears to do nothing at all.

```
function helpSTvar () {
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog-1" ).dialog({
        height: 140,
        modal: true,
        open: function (event, ui) {
            $('.ui-dialog').css('z-index',950);
            $('.ui-widget-overlay').css('z-index',949);
        },
    });
});
}

</script>

<div id="dialog-1" title="Dialog Title goes here...">This my first jQuery UI Dialog!</div>
</head>
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems div tag is in header section, it should be in body

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="dialog-1" title="Dialog Title goes here...">This my first
    jQuery UI Dialog!</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Sudipta.  That does not work either.  I started there.  The only thing that I have been able to get to work is embedding the html directly in the .dialog() function.

Answer (score 0):

Try it!

1. Your `<div>` needs to be inside `<body>` instead of `<head>`;
2. It's not a good pratice to have `$(function(){` inside every function, instead you should do like this:

   ```
   function helpSTvar () {
       $( "#dialog-1" ).dialog({
           height: 140,
           modal: true,
           open: function (event, ui) {
               $('.ui-dialog').css('z-index',950);
               $('.ui-widget-overlay').css('z-index',949);
           },
       });
   }

   $(function(){
       helpSTvar(); // call one or more functions when document's ready
   });
   ```

Comment: Thank you Jhonatan.

I am new to JQuery and Javascript as well.  How is the "$(function()" called?  I do not see any obvious connection in the code.  I know it works but I am curious as to the mechanism that instantiates it.  There are a lot of invisible moving parts in JQuery and that part makes it hard to learn from the surface.

Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome.
"$(function(){" is an alias for "$( document ).ready(function() {" .. So your browser knows that everything inside it must be executed when document's full loaded, in a procedural way.

Javascript is procedural, so everything outside a function must be executed in a procedural way.